# how can I delete an item from an array where certain conditions are met. using angular/typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to delete an item from my array where the value number is equal to 0. I am a beginner and not sure how to do this.

app.component.ts:

```
delete(){
  const filter: number = this.DB[this.number= 0]
  this.DB.splice(filter, 1)

}
```

app.component.html:

```
<button (click)="delete()" class="btn btn-primary">delete num = 0</button>
```

Comment: I would change the name to deleteNum or something not reserved

Comment: What's the problem with the code?

Comment: @mplungjan That makes sense but it's not necessary. You can use reserved names like `new` and `delete` for class methods and use them in the template. These two method names are even very common.

Comment: HTML: 

    <button (click)="deleteNum('num==0')" class="btn btn-primary">delete num = 0</button>

TS: 

    deleteNum(string condition){
     if(condition == 'num==0'){
     this.DB = this.DB.filter(num -> num==0);
     }
    }

Comment: For me it's unclear which element you want to remove. Do you want to remove the element at position 0, `this.number` (which is `0` after `this.number = 0`) or `filter` (which is the element at position 0). `this.DB.splice(filter, 1)` is the same as `this.DB.splice(this.DB[0], 1)`. If `this.DB[0]` is a number `< this.DB.length` the function already deletes an item. Do you want to delete one item or all items that meet a condition?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
delete(){
  this.DB = this.DB.filter(item => item !== 0);    
}
```

Comment: I think it's `this.DB.filter(item => item.number !== 0)` or `this.DB.splice(this.DB.indexOf(item => item.number === 0), 1)`

Comment: thank you for your answer this was helpful for me, im sorry if i worded it poorly.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I understand from your code, there is nothing happening related removing an item which equal to 0. When i was typing this, @dmance answered just before me. If you want to filter some items from an array you use filter method on the array. You dont need to create your own filtering method.

```
this.DB.filter(item=> item !==0)
```

this part of code takes the items which only passes the condition you put in the parenthesis and gather these items in an array. So your new array becomes an array with items only you want. To do that you assign your this.DB to the above line then your this.DB array will be assigned to a new array which doesnt include the item you wanted to be removed.

Comment: thank you, I will try this in my code. sorry for the poor wording of my question